# Как вернуть полный url @property функцией, не строкой в джанго?

Tags: python, django, property

```
@property
def get_full(self):
    if self.type == self.TEXT:
        startstr = ""
        closetag = ""
        endstr = ""
        url_text = ""
    else:
        startstr = self.type
        closetag = ">"
        endstr = "</a>"
        url_text = self.url_text
    test = f"{startstr}{self.content}{closetag}{url_text}{endstr}"
    return test
```

Есть модель с таким методом, (в шаблоне вывожу как {{item.get_full}}) но возвращаю я строку

```
"<a href="tel:88005553535>телефон</a>"
```

можно ли это исправить? не хочу if в шаблон тащить.

Comment: Исправить что? Непонятно, что вы хотите получить вместо строки